# window method and function with parameter in jquery

Tags: jquery

I saw one example. First they created a function which is a method of `window`. Then they called the function parameter. Could you explain this one please?

```
window.image_on = function( dont_show ){

}

if(dont_show)
{
}
else
{
}
};
```

what does `window.image_on`? Did they create any method? In function are they passing any parameter?

1. what does that mean `window.image_on`?
2. In function why he used `function(dont_show)`?

Comment: I think the if statement is within the function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) We can't help you with such fragmentary information. If the code is really as you've shown it, it's a syntax error. It's almost certainly **not** as you've shown it, though.

Comment: @pranav--yes,what does mean?can you explain plz

Comment: just checking `dont_show` is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: `window.image_on = function() {}` is the same as `function image_on() {)` and the second curly bracket puts the rest of the code outside that function

Comment: so he is checking -if true so that statement going to execute. What does mean window.image_on?Ty

Comment: @mplungjan -----so image_on() is a function name and                                       he written one also                      window.imageControlInterval = false; what does means?Ty

Comment: That is just a global variable

Comment: I'd suggest to show the real piece of code instead of this portion which obviously has a missing curly bracket and provides too little context to explain anything